# vagrant omnibus behind proxy

Tags: proxy, vagrant, chef-infra

Ok, I'm trying to update chef-client with vagrant omnibus and proxyconf.  I figured it would pull the proxy from the proxyconf, but it doesn't look that way. Here is my plugin list:

```
vagrant plugin list
    vagrant-login (1.0.1, system)
    vagrant-omnibus (1.4.1)
    - Version Constraint: 1.4.1
    vagrant-proxyconf (1.3.2)
    - Version Constraint: 1.3.2
    vagrant-share (1.1.0, system)
```

and my Vagrant file:

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest

  if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-proxyconf")
    config.proxy.http     = "my proxy"
    config.proxy.https    = "my proxy"
  end
```

When i run it with vagrant up, the machine does not have an updated chef-client.  I tried using the recipe[omnibus_updater] in my run list it still fails because another recipe is failing with a compile failure (because of the older version of chef-client, what a pain in the butt). Any ideas?  Other than creating a new virtual box?

Update:
Running in debug mode doesn't show any errors using :latest.  Updating to 11.12.8 gives the below error

```
vagrant-omnibus:
* '11.12.8' is not a valid version of Chef.
```

Logging into the vm shows $HTTP_PROXY and $HTTPS_PROXY set properly. Running the commands on the built vm works:

```
chef-client -v
Chef: 10.14.2
sudo gem update chef
chef-client -v
Chef: 11.12.8
```

Comment: Change `:latest` to whichever version you want.

Comment: Have you set `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables (on the host)?

Comment: Please run `vagrant up --debug` and gist/pastebin all the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thing 1:
:latest does not error out when it fails to grab the artifact.  Switching to a named version starts to fail to find the artifact which leads me to believe that it isn't getting through the proxy.

Thing 2:
I *think* this is a problem with omnibus in windows.  I've found this pull that may fix it? https://github.com/schisamo/vagrant-omnibus/pull/89.  I think this plug-in isn't using the settings set by poxy-conf.

CURRENTLY USING THIS WORKAROUND:
Set you http proxy in the windows cmd line

```
SET HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy:port
```